# How to upload image with tinymce using file picker handler and images_upload_handler

Tags: javascript, tinymce

By default tinymce image has no browse button where you can click and see a dialog box to choose an image. In my code am trying to add image picker button to tinymce but am finding it difficult to combine it with the images_upload_handler. And lastly how do i use the success callback to update images_upload_base_path.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', "postAcceptor.php");

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure("HTTP Error: " + xhr.status);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != "string") {
                failure("Invalid JSON: " + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why, but for me `images_upload_handler` not works as well... =(

Use `file_picker_callback` instead, like in this example that I found:
https://codepen.io/nirajmchauhan/pen/EjQLpV